# Function that will return the biggest number of consecutive 0's

Tags: recursion, count, binary

For a homework problem, in python we are asked to define in a recursive way a function that will return the biggest number of consecutive 0's in binary for any the number n. We need to use "&" and ">>".

For example, the function should return 2 for n = 44 because its binary representation is 101100.

I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Raphaeliptv7, what did a google search bring up? E.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=recursive+function+coding+challenge

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to solve the task with pen and paper? Do you have to use a specific programming language?

Comment: I added the solution along with explanations, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def max_consecutive_zero_iterative(n):
    res = 0
    streak = 0

    while n > 0:
        if n & 1:
            streak = 0
        else:
            streak += 1
        n = n >> 1
        res = max(res, streak)
    return res


def max_consecutive_zero_recursive(n):
    if n == 0: # end of recursion
        return 0
    value = max_consecutive_zero_recursive(n >> 1) # call to recursive
    current_streak = value & 0xff # current streak is stored in the lowest 8 bits
    longest_streak = value >> 8 # longest streak is stored in the upper bits
    if n & 1: # if we have a bit set 
        return max(longest_streak, current_streak) << 8 # we just return the max value between current_streak and longest_streak, stored in upper bits
    # else if the bit is not set
    current_streak += 1 # we increase our current streak by 1
    # and return the max between the longest_streak and current_streak in the upper bits...
    return max(longest_streak, current_streak) << 8 | current_streak
    # ... but this time we keep information (we don't reset) about the current_streak stored in the lowest 8 bits.


def main():
    print(max_consecutive_zero_recursive(0b1000101111000110000000100110) >> 8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```